# How CSS background property effects the child elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

I was just practicing HTML and CSS when I noticed that when I set the background color of the body to red the whole page including the div boxes become red. I used to think that if we apply the bg color to the body it will only change the background color of the body and not the elements which are inside the body. But why does the background color of my divs also changes to red?? I have to manually set the color for my div so that they will not be the same color as the parent.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

      body{
        background-color:red; // Relevant line!
      }
      .container {
        width: 400px;
        /* border: 1px solid grey; */
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }

      .heading {
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande",
          "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.1);
      }

      /* container 2 styling */
      .css-utility > li:nth-child(1) {
        opacity: 0.7;
      }

      .css-utility > li ul li:nth-child(1) {
        text-transform: lowercase;
      }
      .css-utility > li ul li:nth-child(2) {
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
      .css-utility > li ul li:nth-child(3) {
        text-transform: capitalize;
      }

      .css-utility > li:nth-child(3) p {
        font-weight: 900;
      }
      .css-utility > li:nth-child(4) p {
        line-height: 30px;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        background-color: aliceblue;
      }
      /* container 2 styling ends */

      /* container 3 styling */

      .box , .bg-test {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 10px 0px;
      }

      .container > .box:nth-child(2) {
        background: linear-gradient(35deg, #9b59b6, #3498db);
      }

      .container > .box:nth-child(3) {
        background: repeating-linear-gradient(
          35deg,
          yellow 0px,
          yellow 30px,
          black 30px,
          black 60px
        );
      }
      /* styling for container 3 ends here */

      /* styling for container 4 starts here */
      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h2 align="center">
          Practice
      </h2>
    <!-- container 1 -->
    <div class="container">
      <h4 class="heading">HTML utility tags</h4>
      <hr />
      <ol>
        <li>
          <p>strong tag make the text <strong>bold</strong></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>U tag add <u>underline</u> to the text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>em tag make the text <em>italic</em></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>s tag make the text <s>strickthrough</s></p>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>

    <!-- container 2 -->
    <div class="container">
      <h4 class="heading">Css utility properties</h4>

      <ol class="css-utility">
        <li>
          <p>Opacity css property</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Text Transform Property</p>
          <ul>
            <li>Text transform - Lower Case</li>
            <li>Text transform - Upper Case</li>
            <li>Text transform - Capitalize Case</li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <p>Font-weight property</p>
        </li>

        <li>
          <p>Line Height and letter spacing</p>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <!-- End of the container 2 -->

    <!-- container 3 -->

    <div class="container">
      <h4 class="heading">linear gradient and Strips</h4>

      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- container 3 ends -->

    <!-- container 4 starts -->
    <div class="container bg">
      <h4 class="heading">
        Testing background color
      </h4>
      <div class="bg-test">

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried it with div inside div and the same thing happens. Giving background color to the parent div makes the child div the same color.

I know that this can be reset by using the * selector

```
*
{
   background-color:white;
}
```

My question is why this behavior and I don't know why I never noticed it but anyway it happens. As it's name background color, it should only set the background color of the element to which it's applied and not to the child background color right? but why does it happens?

Comment: Yes, this is the default thing in HTML but, You can set individual colors for the child elements.

Comment: cause the initial value is background-color: transparent; that mean it will show the background of whatever in the background (body in your case )

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color#formal_definition

Comment: Try `div { background-color:white }`

Comment: It is very surprising for me that I noticed it now . For a while I was inactive in web development and looks like I forget quite a few things .

Comment: @justsomeone So how I can set it to something which will only apply the background color to the applied element and not to the child element? I know one method which I already shared at the end of the question but is their is any other way too?

Comment: exactly  that how to do it not sure if there any other way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not agree with your statement that the background-color is inherited. [It simply is not.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color)

What is happening is that your body **contains** the other divs. It is a **block element** in which the other elements live. Being a block element, it expands its width and height to fit its children. Because the default color of the child elements is transparent, they seem red. But they are not.

This can be proved by absolutely positioning a div outside of its parent element. You will see that the child does not have the parent's background color. See my example below.

```css
#red{
  width:100%; 
  height:100px;
  color:white;
  background-color:red;
}

#green{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  color:blue;
  background-color:green;
}

#red-child{
  position:absolute;
  top:150px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="red">
    i'm a red div text which is inside my parent element (relative positioning)     
    <div id="red-child">
        i'm a red div text which is absolutely positioned outside my parent element. Font color is inherited, background color is not.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="green">
      i'm a green div text which is inside my parent element (relative positioning)     
  
  </div>

</body>
```

Conclusion: this is expected behaviour due to their positioning and default transparant background color. If you want the children to have a different color, use a default background-color for all div elements and overwrite when necessary

```
div{ /* for divs only */
    background-color:white;
}

*{ /* for all elements */
    background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks a lot for explaining this. I also thought the same but just a little confused but now its clear and thanks to you .

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `background-color` is `transparent`, so when you didn't specify a background color it shows its parent background color.

Here is a sample, I hope it helps.

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  I am red.
  <div class="div2">
    I am green.
    <div class="div3">
      My background color is transparent so I am green too.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok this is something I have seen but what if we want to change the default behaviour?

Comment: You should set different background for each element that you want to change.

Comment: I find this answer to be confusing. The question is related to background-color, which is not inherited!